# Найти индекс в матрице по заданному значению функцией which

Tags: r

знаю задача тривиальная но что то не получается...

Есть матрица `cbm`, в каждой колонке по два значения в строке

```
opt <- seq(5,900,5)
cbm <- combn(opt,2)
```

Есть вектор  `хх` с двумя значениями

```
xx <- c( 105, 310)
```

нужно найти индекс колонки в матрице `cbm` который соответствует значениям вектора `хх`

Я попробовал так

```
IDX <- which(  cbm[1:2,] == xx )
```

но получил кучу индексов которые не понятно что значат, а индекс должен быть один ведь в матрице `cbm`  нет повторяющихся значений

Что я делаю не так?
Еще попрошу показать как это делается именно через функцию   `which`  могу  сделать циклом но это муторно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения - это использование функции `apply`, которая проходит по каждому столбцу и сравнивает значения столбца с эталоном с помощью `identical`. Стоит отметить, что анонимная функция должна возвращать логические вектор единичной длинны.

```r
> which(apply(cbm, 2, function(x) identical(x, xx)))
[1] 3431
```